# Institution Token is not associated with API Key in Pybliometrics? What's wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, pybliometrics

I am guesting in the another university and trying to use Pybliometrics to parse abstract data for chosen articles. I have a list of doi's and made queries according to them. Unfortunately, even when I am making queries from the university wi-fi I am getting an error:  "Institution Token is not associated with API Key in Pybliometrics". I am using my own api codes from scopus development portal. The code is as following:

```
ab = AbstractRetrieval(eid, view='FULL')
```

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mbbak\PycharmProjects\scotland_vers\scrap_api.py", line 35, in main
Institution Token is not associated with API Key
    ab = AbstractRetrieval(eid, view='FULL')
```

I test api codes with META view, which doesn't require university network and with these codes it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in your configuration file (described at https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html). Apparently you have an entry like `InstToken = WWW` right below `APIKey = XXX`. Try without the InstToken line.